# Wordpress. Как модифицировать админку?

Tags: wordpress

нужно добавить удобный интерфейс для редактирования главной страницы - не ломая верстку.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. В ВП и так можно редактировать главную. Смотря что нужно. Зачем "интерфейс", что в нём должно быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одно из самых простых и универсальных решений - плагин ACF (advanced custom fields).
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/